# Typo3 9: Second Language shows content of both translations with Fallback Mode

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

I've got a Homepage where I have two languages:

- German (Default)
- German easy (Second "Language")

Most of my pages have a translation for `german easy`, but some don't, which is why I activated the Fallback Typ `Fallback Show default language if no translation exists`, at first it seemed to work, since it showed content from the default fallback language `german`, but when I opened up pages where I have a translation to `german easy` as well, I see content from both languages on the page. This problem only occurs when I open the page with `german easy` if I open the page with the default language, it only shows the content of that language.

I really don't know what kind of bug that is, or what its causing. I posted a screenshot of my settings and further below the settings of my config.yaml and the setup.typoscript, if that might help anyhow.

Btw, if I turn the fallback type to strict the bug doesn't occur, but then again pages with no translation don't work.

Default Language:
[image: German base]
Second Language:
[image: German Easy, second language]

config.yaml

```yaml
base: /
baseVariants: {  }
errorHandling:
  -
    errorCode: '404'
    errorHandler: Page
    errorContentSource: 't3://page?uid=20'
languages:
  -
    title: Deutsch
    enabled: true
    base: /
    typo3Language: de
    locale: de_DE
    iso-639-1: de
    navigationTitle: Deutsch
    hreflang: de-DE
    direction: ''
    flag: de
    languageId: '0'
  -
    title: Deutsch_vereinfacht
    enabled: true
    base: /de/
    typo3Language: de
    locale: de_DE
    iso-639-1: de
    navigationTitle: Deutsch_vereinfacht
    hreflang: de-DE
    direction: ''
    fallbackType: fallback
    fallbacks: '0'
    flag: de
    languageId: '2'
rootPageId: 18
routes: {  }
```

setup.typoscript

```
config {
    absRefPrefix = auto
    cache_period = 86400
    debug = 0
    disablePrefixComment = 1
    doctype = html5
    extTarget = _blank
    index_enable = 1
    index_externals = 1
    index_metatags = 1
    inlineStyle2TempFile = 1
    intTarget =
    linkVars = L
    metaCharset = utf-8
    no_cache = 0
    pageTitleFirst = 1
    prefixLocalAnchors = all
    removeDefaultJS = 0
    renderCharset = utf-8
    sendCacheHeaders = 1
    uniqueLinkVars = 1

    // Disable image upscaling
    noScaleUp = 1

    // Compression and concatenation of CSS and JS Files
    compressCss = 0
    compressJs = 0
    concatenateCss = 0
    concatenateJs = 0
}
```

Anyone has an idea what causes this bug or how to fix it?

Comment: Your TYPO3 version is known to have language-related bugs. Do you have the option to update or to test it in a most recent TYPO3 10.4?

Comment: Puh, 10.4 would be a huge jump where a lot of things could probably break (we got some plugins which don't support 10 yet). I'm currently at 9.15.19 and wanted to update today to 9.15.21, but I guess they both share the same bug? Then maybe I really have to think about going for 10.4. You don't happen to know if there is a workaround for that?

Comment: first I'd test it on TYPO3 10.4 without much data, just enough to make a test. If the fault there still exists an update won't be sooo promising.

Comment: with updating extensions I could help, just not for free, if it's not only about small tasks.

Comment: Yeah thats true. I might give that a shot, hopefully it'll work

Comment: Please add information on how you actually render the content elements. This can make a huge difference. E.g. `page.100 =< styles.content.get` or https://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package/blob/master/Configuration/TypoScript/ContentElement/Helper/DynamicContent.typoscript or even https://viewhelpers.fluidtypo3.org/fluidtypo3/vhs/5.0.1/Content/Get.html. Even your lib.contentElement could be interesting (is it default fluid_styled_content?).

Comment: I reproduced your behaviour with v:content.get/.render in https://forge.typo3.org/issues/90261

Answer (score 0):

In the site-config you've to use the fallbackType: free
and set your fallback language, in this case german (ID = 0 ), as fallback.

```
-
title: Deutsch_vereinfacht
enabled: true
base: /de/
typo3Language: de
locale: de_DE
iso-639-1: de
navigationTitle: Deutsch_vereinfacht
hreflang: de-DE
direction: ''
fallbackType: free
fallbacks: '0'
flag: de
languageId: '2'
```

Then only the translated content is shown and in the navigation all not translated pages will be shown as well in the fallback-language